# JSON without double quotes & spaces in values, is difficult to parse

Tags: json, jackson-databind, fasterxml

Hi I am trying to parse below JSON data
I am trying to get JSON parsed into Java object, but its failing

```
{
  VERIFY_SAMPLE_RESPONSE: {
    LOCATION_D: {
      ADDRESS_LINE2: null,
      ADDRESS_LINE1: 770 11Th Ave,
      COUNTRY: US,
      STATE: NY
    }
  }
}
```

My Respective classes

```
@Data
public class MyResponse {
    @JsonProperty("VERIFY_SAMPLE_RESPONSE")
    public SampleResponse sampleResponse;
}
```

SampleResponse.java file

```
@Data
public class SampleResponse {
    @JsonProperty("LOCATION_D")
    public LocationData locationData;
}
```

LocationData.java

```
@Data
public class LocationData {
    @JsonProperty("ADDRESS_LINE2")
    public Object addressLine2;
    @JsonProperty("ADDRESS_LINE1")
    public String addressLine1;    
    @JsonProperty("COUNTRY")
    public String country;
    @JsonProperty("STATE")
    public String state;
}
```

My Utility using Jackson-faster XML to conversion from JSON to Java object

```
public static <T> T conversion(String jsonData, Class<T> obj) {
        try {
            mapper.disable(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES);
            mapper.configure(JsonParser.Feature.ALLOW_UNQUOTED_FIELD_NAMES, true);
            return mapper.readValue(jsonData, obj);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

I am calling using below ways

```
conversion(rawData, MyResponse.class);
```

I am getting below error

```
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('1' (code 49)): was expecting comma to separate Object entries
 at [Source: (String)"{VERIFY_SAMPLE_RESPONSE:{LOCATION_D:{ADDRESS_LINE2:null, ADDRESS_LINE1:770 11Th Ave, COUNTRY:US, STATE:NY}}}"; line: 1, column: 107]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser._constructError(JsonParser.java:2391) ~[jackson-core-2.13.1.jar:2.13.1]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.base.ParserMinimalBase._reportError(ParserMinimalBase.java:735) ~[jackson-core-2.13.1.jar:2.13.1]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.base.ParserMinimalBase._reportUnexpectedChar(ParserMinimalBase.java:659) ~[jackson-core-2.13.1.jar:2.13.1]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.ReaderBasedJsonParser._skipComma(ReaderBasedJsonParser.java:2382) ~[jackson-core-2.13.1.jar:2.13.1]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.ReaderBasedJsonParser.nextFieldName(ReaderBasedJsonParser.java:947) ~[jackson-core-2.13.1.jar:2.13.1]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.vanillaDeserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:320) ~[jackson-databind-2.13.1.jar:2.13.1]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:176) ~[jackson-databind-2.13.1.jar:2.13.1]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.impl.MethodProperty.deserializeAndSet(MethodProperty.java:129) ~[jackson-databind-2.13.1.jar:2.13.1]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.vanillaDeserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:313) ~[jackson-databind-2.13.1.jar:2.13.1]
    ... 16 common frames omitted

Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('1' (code 49)): was expecting comma to separate Object entries
```

Comment: "JSON" without double quotes (around property names and strings) **is not JSON**. You can't use a JSON parser to parse it.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I am referring to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36582892/convert-json-string-without-quotes-into-a-map