# Convert nested JSON to HashMap

Tags: json, nested, hashmap, objectmapper

I have the below String which represents a nested json:

```
{ history:{name:[{value:Jim, details:Final}],job:[{value:Builder, details:Pending}]} }
```

In Java, I would like to convert it to its equivalent HashMap<String, Object> type. The Object is technically an ArraList<Map<String, Object>>. I can get this to work by manually wrapping escaped quotes around the strings like below:

```
{ \"history\":{\"name\":[{\"value\":\"Jim\", \"details\":\"Final\"}]} }
```

Is there a way to do this formatting automatically via some function. I have tried to use ObjectMapper as below with the string above but it creates an empty Map. Can anyone assist?

```
Map<String, Object> map = new ObjectMapper().readValue(jsonString, HashMap.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work for field names

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();                          
objectMapper.configure(JsonParser.Feature.ALLOW_UNQUOTED_FIELD_NAMES, true);
Map<String, String> Shop_Details = objectMapper.readValue(jsonString, HashMap.class);
```

Although, values will still need to have quotes. You can try GSON instead. See More:

[Convert json string without quotes into a map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36582892/convert-json-string-without-quotes-into-a-map)

[Gson parse unquoted value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20557131/gson-parse-unquoted-value)

Comment: Thanks, as values needed quotes I cannot use ObjectMapper. I tried to use GSON instead but then realised it doesnt like values with spaces and throws a MalformedJSONException on the fromJson() function. The below code is what I have so far:


    JsonReader jr = new JsonReader(new StringReader(jsonString.trim()));
    jr.setLenient(true);
    Map<String, Object> resultMap = new Gson().fromJson(jr, new TypeToken<Map<String, Object>>() {
    }.getType());

Comment: @MisterIbbs Spaces are why quotes are needed, So yeah GSON would try to do as much as possible but unquoted spaces, commas in string will cause trouble